# Online tool to publish aggregated podcast feed with enclosures?

Tags: podcasts, aggregation, podcatcher

I listen to many podcasts.  I'd like to share the best among them with an audience via an RSS feed, but I want that feed to include the original enclosure.  The idea is that the audience puts my aggregated feed into their podcatcher, which will see the enclosures and download the podcasts I've handpicked automatically.  The podcasts are from various sources, and my solution shouldn't require my hosting the MP3 files (rather, my RSS, which is aggregated, should still point back to the original hosting location for the podcast audio files).

Google Reader's shared tag feeds *would* be perfect, but they don't include enclosures.

Is there a tool online somewhere that will let me manage and publish a feed like this?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you mean by "original enclosure"?

Comment: The RSS of a podcast typically includes a tag called "enclosure".  It contains information about the media file associated with a given podcast episode.  When you aggregate podcast RSS feeds with tools like feedrinse.com and (I think) Yahoo Pipes, the "enclosure" tag is not included.  So, if you point a podcatcher at that feed, it won't download any files.  It seems like it should be possible to include the enclosure tag in a feed created with Yahoo Pipes.  I've tried before and don't recall succeeding.  That was a while back.  Maybe I should try again (maybe someone's already done it?).

Comment: Ah, perhaps I should have Googled it first... If you use delicious, then you can bookmark a link to the mp3 with a particular tag. It will automatically create a tag feed, with enclosures for the mp3 files. Also, Yahoo Pipes is able to manipulate enclosures (e.g., http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=a5a9d881ddb65e81ce19b6b8504cc599 and http://pipes.yahoo.com/earth2marsh/deliciouspodcast).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) allows you to create a feed that is an aggregate of multiple feeds, but I'm not sure how you would select your preferred entries.

Comment: How have you used Pipes to create this feed?  I've been doing something similar with a Google Reader public tag, but that will go away soon.

Answer (score 0):

[feedrinse.com](http://www.feedrinse.com/) let you aggregate and filter rss but I don't know about enclosures