# How can I create my own private RSS feed of selected podcasts?

Tags: itunes, rss, ipod-touch, podcasts

I would like to be able to browse the Internet and "drag" available MP3 files of various podcast episodes into my own private [RSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) feed.

I would like to then subscribe to this RSS feed with iTunes.

Do you know of any applications or services that would do this?

(I subscribe to IT Conversations and they have a private RSS feed that you can create of their episodes. I like this feature very much. If only I had such a feature that would work more generally).

One of the reasons I am looking for this, that my [iPod Touch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPod_Touch) has problems handling podcast playlists that span multiple RSS feeds.

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/110165/online-tool-to-publish-aggregated-podcast-feed-with-enclosures

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could bookmark the mp3 file in [Delicious](http://delicious.com/) with a specific tag, e.g. `podcast`. Delicious will automatically create an Atom feed for this tag, which you can subscribe to from your iPod, e.g.:

```
http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/rss/username/podcasts
```

Comment: Woah, that is slick.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a *bundle* in [Google Reader](http://google.com/reader).

1. Create a folder in Google Reader called *Podcasts*
2. Add all of your podcast RSS feeds to this folder.
3. Access the menu for the folder and select *Create Bundle*
4. Select *Save*. (Uncheck *Add to my shared items* if you don't want it public)
5. Click on *Add a link to your website or blog*
6. Subscribe to the Atom feed provided on the right side of the page.

Answer (score 1):

There is also Yahoo Pipes, an online tool for mashing RSS feeds together: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/